# Unity Quaternion method call error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I have written this code but get this error:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation (Vector3(0, 0, 0), Vector3(250, 0, 0));
```

> error: Expression denotes a type, where a variable, value or method group was expected

Comment: you mean `Quaternion.FromToRotation (new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(250, 0, 0));`

Answer (score 2):

The `Quaternion.FromToRotation` function takes two `Vector3` as parameter. To pass the `Vector3` to this function you must create new instance of it. You do this with the `new` keyword. Add new to each time you created new Vector.

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(250, 0, 0));
```

There is also a static variable `Vector3.zero` that create new Vector as `0`,`0`,`0`. You can also use that as your first parameter:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.zero, new Vector3(250, 0, 0));
```